# jquery submitting a select form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, form-submit

I have a table that contains invoices which means there are multiple rows, each row contains a form in which the user can submit a payment for, I initially intercept the forms submit and send off to stripe the payment information and when I receive a response i then will want to add the token we received from stripe and then submit the form. How can I submit the specific form after I have received a response from stripe with jquery?

Any help is appreciated, thank you for your time.

My current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $form = $('form');
console.log($form);
$form.submit(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    console.log("form submit event clicked");
    if ($('#paymentMethod').val() == 'Saved Card') {
        console.log("reaching if statement");
        // No new card is used so just submit the form. I NEED HELP HERE THIS IS CURRENTLY NOT SUBMITTING CORRECTLY.
        $form.submit();
    } else {
        console.log("reaching else statement");
        //Send payment information to payment processor provider.
        return false;
    }
});

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    if (response.error) {
        console.log("reaching error statement");
    } else {
        console.log("reaching successful response statement");

        // Done with payment processing, submit the form. THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP WITH, ITS CURRENTLY NOT SUBMITTING.
        $form.get(0).submit();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Most of our attention span is like 5 seconds. Pasting a chunk of code won't help us help you =(

Comment: Understood but my chunk of code is describing my scenario which isnt very much code which shows the reader how im obtaining my form then sending payment to my payment processor then when i get the information back I need to submit my form. Not sure what about my code you didnt like but sorry?